# Manipulate MySQL results through a foreach loop, using mysqli_ procedural methods

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

My first question I believe is simple, yet the answer eludes me. I wish to return my MySQL query results by a `foreach` loop, but I've gone wrong with my syntax somewhere. This is all the code I have so far:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM records";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
//$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
foreach ($row as $rowx) {
$datex = $result['nowdate'];
    echo $datex;
}
```

Currently, my `echo` does nothing, but the page still loads.

Once I've got my `foreach` loop working, I wish to check each `$datex` (stored in the format `d-m-Y`) against the current `date('W')` and count the number of results which match this current calendar week.

Any help with my `foreach` syntax and then my advanced problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: `$row` - it's array of column values- not array of rows

Comment: Why not just do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM records WHERE nowdate > {startofweekdate}` or something similar?

Comment: Great idea, I've implemented it and it works wonderfully. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change it to

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $datex = $row['nowdate'];
    echo $datex;
}
```

Comment: Marked as correct, as a `while()` loop is the correct way of displaying the results I wanted instead of a `foreach()` loop, even though I didn't use it in the end.